# Error 'dispatcherServlet' al consumir web service Rest con Spring

Tags: java, webservice, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Buenos dias, hace ya tiempo estoy intentando solucionar este inconveniente, el proble que tengo es que eh desarrollado una aplicacion utilizando Spring, en la misma tengo un web service Rest el cual al momento de intentar consumir me sale el siguiente error:

**Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'**

Y desde el browser me da el siguiente mensaje;

**Whitelabel Error Page**

**This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.**

A continuacion detallo mis archivos del sistema:

WebServiceBack.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"municipalidad.domain"})
public class WebServiceBack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebServiceBack.class, args);
    }


}
```

ConfigApp.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ConfigApp {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
       DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
       dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
       dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.48.25:1521/db");
       dataSource.setUsername( "user" );
       dataSource.setPassword( "pass" );
       return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {
       LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
       em.setDataSource(dataSource());
       em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.baeldung.persistence.model" });

       JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
       em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
       em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

       return em;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
       JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
       transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

       return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
       return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
       Properties properties = new Properties();
       properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
       properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
       return properties;
    }
}
```

WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
//    @Bean
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/*").addResourceLocations("/");
    }

}
```

PadronResource.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class PadronResource {

    public final PadronService padronService;

    public PadronResource(PadronService padronService) {
        super();
        this.padronService = padronService;
    }



    @GetMapping("/padron/{cuit}")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Padron> getPadron(@PathVariable Long cuit) {
        Padron retorno = new Padron();
        retorno = padronService.getPersona(cuit);
        return new ResponseEntity(retorno, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- APP -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- DOMAIN -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- REST -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc6 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>



  </dependencies>
```

En el browser para consumir pongo:

http://localhost:8080/api/padron/20999999991

Comment: ¡Buenas Nico! ¿Podrías colocar también el stacktrace para saber qué error sucede y atacarlo directamente?

Comment: El error que sale es el siquiente: 'dispatcherServlet' Del lado del browser no llego directamente a consumir el servicio, o sea el error da directamente antes de consumirlo. Estoy viendo por el lado de la configuracion de los servlet mapping de spring boot, pero aun no encuentro resultado positivo.

Comment: Te sugiero editar la pregunta y agregar el detalle allí.

Comment: Listo, tambien agregue el mensaje que me larga desde el browser

Comment: No veo ningún stacktrace completo que permita evaluar el problema. Más bien el mensaje *Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'* significa que está levantando la aplicación. Si no ves un mensaje como *Startup at <minutos>:<segundos>* entonces tu servicio no ha iniciado.

Comment: Si esta iniciado, es muy raro el mensaje, el tema es que cuando quiero consumir el web service en la consola veo ese mensaje y no anda directamente, no se ven. Creo que viene por un tema de configuracion, ya que funcionaba y cuando agregue las dependencias de Spring-boot para hacer los CrudRepository no anduvo mas. No puedo dar con el problema de configuracion de los servlet mapping. Ahora estoy viendo: ServletRegistrationBean

Comment: Bueno, eso se vería bien expresado en el stacktrace que se pinta en el log. En serio, por favor colócalo aquí, con eso tendremos las pistas para ver qué problema en concreto tienes.

Comment: 2017-09-22 12:40:25.103  INFO 340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-09-22 12:40:25.103  INFO 340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-09-22 12:40:25.124  INFO 340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 21 ms

Comment: Muy bien, ese es el log al iniciar la aplicación. Luego de eso invocas al servicio y el log debe mostrar los errores que indicas. Ese mensaje es el que necesitamos para evaluar el problema.

Comment: No me da ningin error, ahi esta el problema. Es mas en el fornt me sale error de no encontrar el servicio. El tema es que con la misma URL funcionaba. No se si por algun motivo cuando añadi Spring cambio algo en la url del servicio y por eso no lo encuentra quizas o ya no reconoce los Rest

Comment: Ya solucione el error, el tema es que la anotacion: "@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"municipalidad.domain"})" lo que hace es decirle a spring que desde ahi se leen todos los archivos del proyecto, lo cual no funcionaba nunguno que este en otro lugar fuera de domain, lo solucione poniendo: @ComponentScan(basePackages= {"municipalidad"})